# terraform provisioner variable type listofmaps doesn't work for tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

In Terraform, I am using null_resource provider to create aws eventbridge (custom event bus). Since terraform is NOT providing inbuild resource type to create custom event bus.

```
# cat main.tf 
resource "null_resource" "event_bus" {
    triggers = {
          event_bus_name = var.event_bus_name
    }
    provisioner "local-exec" {
          command = "aws events create-event-bus --name ${var.event_bus_name} --tags ${var.event_bus_tags}"
   
    }
    provisioner "local-exec" {
          when = destroy
 
          command = "aws events delete-event-bus --name ${self.triggers.event_bus_name}"
    }
}
```

I am defining the variable for tags as below

```
# cat variable.tf 
variable "event_bus_tags" {
   type = list(map(any))
}
variable "event_bus_name" {
   type = string
}
```

and I am calling the variable in auto.tfvars as below

```
# cat var.auto.tfvars 
event_bus_tags = [
  {
    "Key": "environment", "Value": "dev"
  },
  {
    "Key": "type", "Value": "custom"
  }
]

event_bus_name = "my-event-bus"
```

but I am getting the bellow error.

```
# terraform apply --auto-approve
null_resource.event_bus: Creating...
Error: Invalid template interpolation value: Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.
```

the command line works just fine.

```
aws events create-event-bus --name test --tags '[ { "Key": "env", "Value": "dev" } ]'
```

Not sure what would be the appropriate variable type for tags, incase of "Key" & "Value" are string type.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the Terraform object into a JSON string. Terraform provides the [jsonencode](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsonencode.html) function for this.

```
command = "aws events create-event-bus --name ${var.event_bus_name} --tags ${jsonencode(var.event_bus_tags)}"
```

Comment: awesome Many Thanks @Mark, its working as expected
here is the updated command in main.tf
`command = "aws events create-event-bus --name ${var.event_bus_name} --tags '${jsonencode(var.event_bus_tags)}'"`